# What is the difference between API and Webservice?

Tags: web-services, api

can anybody give me some example?

Comment: You should google to find answers to these kind of questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A web service will expose an API.

Not all APIs are web services - any library will have an API.

APIs are the public interface of a piece of code - it is what you can call from within your code. It *may* be a web service, but it could also be a JavaScript library, a compiled library for your platform (say .NET assembly, java JAR, a PE DLL and more).

Answer (score 1):

API is more of an abstract concept it is a programatic interface for your application it can be implemented in veraity of methods and technologies. Webservice is a spesific implemenation of such concept that using SOAP and HTTP technologies.

Answer (score 1):

API is an acronym that stands for Application Programming Interface, as such it can be used to describe any piece of software you can use inside another software to develop an application or part of it. As an example the library/module/classes that allow you to open a file and read its contents is an API: you don't know how it works but you can use it into your software to achieve a possible complicate goal.

A web service is usually a remote piece of software capable of responding to web requests which provides some sort of functionality. Usually the word is used to indicate SOAP web services, but a RESTful application is a web service as well. In a broader sense of the word any web site is a web service as they provide `a service over the web`, but usually we do not consider them in that category because we refer to machine-to-machine interactions.

Now, if you consider that a web service can be used by your application to deliver part of your application logic then a web service **IS** an API.

Answer (score 0):

They are same thing, Web Service is a specific type of API that is accessed over the web.

Facebook - offers a Web service / API

Twitter - offers a Web service / API

Windows  - offers an API

An "Application Programming Interface" was originally used to describe the interface offered by system software(Windows) to be used by application programs (word, Microsoft paint etc...). The term API has since then evolved to encompass pretty much any software interface.

A web service is a software interface that is accessed over the web.

IMO API's that are accessed over the web should only be called Web Services, However the masses have started calling them API's - so that is what it is.

I wrote more about API's here: http://www.woodstitch.com/resources/what-is-an-api.php